# Group dictionaries according to its key

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to group the dictionaries returned from api inside for loop by its given key.Values for `type` and `query` are dynamic, depends from request params from user

```
 def process_item(self, item, spider):
    print(f"item {item}")
```

prints

```
  {
      "type": "sponsored_product", 
      "query": "leather wallet", 
      "asin": "B092S9S3G3"
  },
  {
      "type": "search_product", 
      "query": "leather wallet", 
      "asin": "B092S91234"
  },
  {
      "type": "search_product", 
      "query": "mens wallet", 
      "asin": "B092S9789"
  }
```

So what I am trying to achieve is to group them and save in to json file as list of dicts

```
  [
     "mens wallet": [
          {
            "search_product": [
                 {
                    "asin": "asin number123"
                 },
                 {
                    "asin": "asin number567"
                 },
               
            ],
            "sponsored_product": [
                 {
                    "asin": "asin number123"
                 },
                 {
                    "asin": "asin number567"
                 },
            ]
         }
      ],
    "leather wallet": [
          {
            "search_product": [
                 {
                    "asin": "asin number123"
                 },
                 {
                    "asin": "asin number567"
                 },
               
            ],
            "sponsored_product": [
                 {
                    "asin": "asin number123"
                 },
                 {
                    "asin": "asin number567"
                 },
               
            ]
         }
      ],
   ]
```

I was thinking of saving it first to the file and perform grouping later  but I cant make it work.Do you have Idea on how to group them before saving to a json file?

```
    for k, v in item.items():
         with open("list1.json", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
             json.dump(v, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

UPDATE:

So i tried the following code

```
import itertools
import json

buck = [
    {"type": "sponsored_product", "query": "leather wallet", "asin": "B092S9S3G3"},
    {"type": "search_product", "query": "leather wallet", "asin": "B092S91234"},
    {"type": "search_product", "query": "mens wallet", "asin": "B092S9789"},
]


def key_func(k):
    return k["query"]


def key_func2(k):
    return k["type"]


info = sorted(buck, key=key_func)
groups = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(buck, key_func):
    # print(list(group))

    groups.append({key: list(group)})
print(groups)
```

And with output

```
[
     {
         'leather wallet': [
             {
                'type': 'sponsored_product', 
                'query': 'leather wallet', 
                'asin': 'B092S9S3G3'
            }, 
            {
                'type': 'search_product', 
                'query': 'leather wallet', 
                'asin': 'B092S91234'
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        'mens wallet': [
            {
                'type': 'search_product',
                'query': 'mens wallet', 
                'asin': 'B092S9789'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What's remaining is to group by type

Comment: your wanted structure has plenty of redundant data  `"search_product": [{"type":"search_product", ..}, {"type":"search_product", ..}` and (to me at first glace) unclear grouping (leather wallet that contains searhced prods and sponsored prods where sponsored prods contain sponsored and searched products. You may want to make this a bit clearer - this looks like a waste of storage space.

Comment: @PatrickArtneryeah I agree, I updated the desired result for more clearer